# Flurl with Azure AD Authentication

Tags: .net-core, blazor, flurl

I'm trying to integrate Azure AD Authentication into a blazor WASM hosted app. I've got it working correctly with the default HTTP client, but I'd like to use Flurl.

This is what I have with the default HTTPClient setup;

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("{APP ASSEMBLY}.ServerAPI", client => 
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
.AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
.CreateClient("{APP ASSEMBLY}.ServerAPI"));
```

It seems I'm unable to replicate this behavior with Flurl. I've tried to override the default IHTTPClientFactory, but I can't seem to get it to accept the BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler to pass the token along from Azure AD with the Flurl requests.

https://flurl.dev/docs/configuration/#httpclientfactory

Comment: Can I ask what you mean by **accept** the ```BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler```?  Do you mean that the  ```BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler``` is not called? Or is the handler invoked but no token is added to the Authorization Header?

Comment: @Justthebenno I need to register BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler with Flurl somehow, but I'm not sure how to do it. It works fine if i use it with the regular httpclient. If its not registered with flurl the requests will not have the token.

Comment: @Dylan , were you able to solve this? Have the same issue

Comment: Nope. Ended up just using the regular http client for this in the end